# Is possible bind with IF ELSE statement

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

if Name is empty or null, bind with NameOpt
Something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding if Name ? Name : NameOpt}" />
```

Comment: You can as described below with the DataTrigger but this should probably be accomplished in the ViewModel. Can you illustrate why you need to do it this way because I may be able to offer a more elegant solution.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Ok i have two monitors, one function, two strings Name and NameOpt, if NameOpt is null both screens should print Name, if NameOpt is not null screen one print Name and screen 2 NameOpt, i hope it make sense. I just ask if there is option for IF else in XAML

Comment: There is also [PriorityBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding(v=vs.110).aspx), which you may use with both Name and NameOpt Bindings. NameOpt would have to return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue to activate the NameOpt Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataTriger](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/) to achieve the behavior

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
           <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding NameOpt}"/>
       </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this one

Answer (score 1):

Well you could with a `DataTrigger` and there is nothing stopping you, but  that's arguably a bad way to do binding, particularly from a MVVM point of view.  *Generally* triggers are for changing a property based on conditions either in the XAML itself or a particular property in the VM.  It's kind of weird to do dynamic binding to a property depending upon the state of whether a VM property is null or not.

To do so purely from the VM try, your view should bind to a single property like `Name`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

...and in the processing in your VM do something like:

```
public string Name { get ; set; } // TODO: add usual property changed stuff

void UpdateStuff()
{
    // perhaps update Name and NameOpt here
    // ...

    // Now update the exposed property
    Name ? Name : NameOpt
}
```